# using regular expression in c# with ñ

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex `"(^[0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]{1,30}$)"`
to validate letters numbers and special characters, but doesn't work because in ther lines

```
Regex r = new Regex(re1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(dato[colIndex - 1]);  

   if (m.Success)
```

`m.Success` returns false, the variable dato[colIndex-1] contains the string "ACUÑA"

I prove too this:

`[\\u00D1]` //for this I use a string="Ñ"

```
\\w
```

and doesn't work either

Comment: This site accepts questions in English only, so I have edited your post to remove the non-English portions.

Comment: ok thanks, i'm sorry, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following pattern should work correctly.

```
string pattern = @"^([\w ]{0,30})$";
```

If not, probably the text you got from your database has a character that is invisible.
You can try the following sample to see for yourself.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var re =  new Regex(@"^([\w ]{0,30})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        //Console.WriteLine(re.Match("ACUÑA").Success);
        Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch("ACUÑA")); // Should print "True"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes my friend print true , 
how could solve ? can you help me please ? , the text is a string of a .txt  the problem not is the regex else the text ?

Comment: I solved my friend , the error was the encoding that i used. i change to Default so, get to "ñ" and not get (?) the error character , good bye and thanks